# Laravel hasMany with a filter

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

This is more like a recommendation of how to structure my database probably. Basically, I have a model `App\Project` and I have another model `App\Asset`.

App\Project hasMany App\Asset:

```
public function assets() {
   return $this->hasMany('App\Asset');
}
```

The assets are different images and the `assets` table has a `type` column.

So on the page where I actually display the project, what I want to do is to display an image that has `original` set as a type, as a starting / first image and then have others follow up. (all the assets are optional. not all the projects will have an `original` image.)

How can I achieve that? Should I filter an array and sort of cut the `original` out of an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve your problem with [Query Scopes](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#query-scopes).

An example to get all assets with type as `original`:

**Asset model:**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
```

---

```
public function scopeOfOriginalType(Builder $query) {
    return $query->where('type', 'original');
}
```

**Controller:**

```
$project = Project::find(1);
$assets = $project->assets()->ofOriginalType()->get();
```

Comment: Thank you, just what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

A less complicated method to achieve this might be just using a `where` clause on the relation:

```
public function assets() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Asset')->where("type", "original");
}
```